# How does Anarchy work?

Tags: civilization-6

No mention of it in the game documentation that I can find. When do you get anarchy? How exactly does it work? Any additional thoughts on when it is worthwhile or just always avoid it? I have played a few games and never had anarchy and suddenly I have a game with anarchy.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this has helped. If not let us know that too so we can get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Anarchy is triggered when you switch to a government type your civilization has previously had.

It lasts a small number of turns, and during anarchy, no yields are accrued (though you can still command units normally).